# For five consecutive scenes, What is the probability that in three of them there will be one protagonist and one secondary character?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

A TV series with 10 recurring characters. Four of these characters are protagonists, while the remaining six are secondary characters. For each scene of the TV series, the probability that any of the protagonists will be in it is 0.75.Instead, the probability that any secondary character will be in it is 0.25.

How do I calculate the probability that in 5 consecutive scenes, in three of them there will be one protagonist and one secondary character. I know it is something to do with binomials but I'm not sure how to fill it in. I think I need to find the probability that they will be in 1 scene and then do the binomial equation.

Comment: Are the probabilities independent? And do you mean _exactly_ one main character and _exactly_ one secondary character, or _at least_ one?

Comment: The probabilities are independent, and its exactly 1 main and 1 secondary character.

Comment: The statement is quite vague.  Are you requiring that the protagonist and the secondary be together for exactly three scenes?   Is it ok if the protagonist is in all $5$ by the secondary is in only $3$?  None of the various possibilities are difficult to calculate, but as it stands it is hard to guess which you are looking for.

Comment: I think its the probability that they are together for exactly three scenes, but you are right it is tricky to tell.